# java.nio.channels.SocketChannel is a restricted class Error integrating Memcache with springmvc controller and appengine

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, memcached

I have added the following bean definition and dependencies for integrate my springmvc application deployed on appengine with memcache

```
 <!-- Memcache Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.simple-spring-memcached</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cache</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.simple-spring-memcached</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmemcached-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
===========================================================================

<bean name="cacheManager" class="com.google.code.ssm.spring.SSMCacheManager">
        <property name="caches">
            <set>
                <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.spring.SSMCache">
                    <constructor-arg name="cache" index="0" ref="defaultCache"/>
                    <!-- 5 minutes -->
                    <constructor-arg name="expiration" index="1" value="300"/>
                    <!-- @CacheEvict(..., "allEntries" = true) doesn't work -->
                    <constructor-arg name="allowClear" index="2" value="false"/>
                </bean>
            </set>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean name="defaultCache" class="com.google.code.ssm.CacheFactory">
        <property name="cacheName" value="defaultCache"/>
        <property name="cacheClientFactory">
            <bean name="cacheClientFactory" class="com.google.code.ssm.providers.xmemcached.MemcacheClientFactoryImpl"/>
        </property>
        <property name="addressProvider">
            <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.config.DefaultAddressProvider">
                <property name="address" value="127.0.0.1:11211"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="configuration">
            <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.providers.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="consistentHashing" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>
</beans>
```

But I keep getting the below error

Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'com.google.code.ssm.spring.SSMCache#52f1a4a9' of type [com.google.code.ssm.spring.SSMCache] while setting bean property 'caches' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.google.code.ssm.spring.SSMCache#52f1a4a9' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'defaultCache' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultCache': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.channels.SocketChannel is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.channels.SocketChannel is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)

Comment: yes, you're right, this class is restricted and you cannot use it on gae. what was the question?

Comment: So how do i get memcache working with springmvc controller on app engine  since i get an initialization error for my bean 'defaultCache' ?

Comment: for example you could start using something different than `SSMCache`